# Вывести сумму чисел, кратных 3 или 5

Tags: python, циклы

Необходимо из числа которое введет пользователь, вывести сумму чисел, кратных 3 или 5

Пробую так:

```
a = int(input('Введите число: '))
for i in range(a):
    if i % 3 == 0 or i % 5 == 0:
        print(sum(i))
```

Получаю ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/user/Projects/Examples/err.py", line 4, in <module>
    print(sum(i))
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Такой код, тоже ничего не меняет:

```
print(int(sum(i)))
```

Та же самая ошибка будет.

Подскажите, где я ошибся?

Comment: Приведите код текстом, а не фотографией, пожалуйста

Comment: Примите добрый совет, поставьте PyCharm Community. Он бесплатный, обидные ошибки типа этой будет подсвечивать в процессе написания кода.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробую привести более понятный для топикстартера код без генераторов

```
rng = int(input('Введите число: '))     # задаем длину диапазона чисел
useful = []                             # создаем список в который будут добавляться числа удовлетворяющие йсловию
for i in range(rng):                    # для каждого числа в диапазоне
    if i % 3 == 0 or i % 5 == 0:        # проверяем условие
        useful.append(i)                # если удовлетворяет условию добавляем в список

print(sum(useful))                      # суммируем все числа списка и выводим
```

> Ваша ошибка заключалась в том, что вы применяли `sum` к неитерируему объекту `int`

Ну и если уж с генератором, то, ИМХО, так:

```
print(sum(i for i in range(int(input('Введите число: '))) if i % 3 == 0 or i % 5 == 0))
```

> Обратите внимание на то, что будут обработаны все числа ДО `rng` (в Вашем случае `a`) поскольку значение обозначающее правую границу диапазона в диапазон не входит. Что-бы получить диапазон включающий значение заданной правой границы можно использовать `for i in range(a + 1)`

Answer (score 0):

Ваша ошибка в том, что вы пытаетесь просуммировать **одно** число. Можно завести перед циклом переменную, равную нулю, и каждый раз в цикле, когда условие выполняется, прибавлять число к этой переменной. А в конце после окончания цикла просто распечатать получившуюся переменную.

Или проще сделать, например, так:

```
a = int(input())

print(sum(i for i in range(a+1) if not i % 3 or not i % 5))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
a = int(input())                                                 
sum = 0 #переменная где будет высчитываться сумма                             
for i in range(a):                                            
    if i%3 == 0 or i%5 == 0:                                
            sum += i #прибавляем i

print(sum)
```